# Understanding a Kivy app's profile

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have a kivy app, which sometimes responds quite slow.
I went on and profiled it in Pycharm, and this is what I got (partly):
[image]
You'll see that considerable running time is spent on the builtin function `dir()`, which I saw is being called from is_dead (also considerable time).
Does anyone know what is_dead is used for?

Also noticable is that a lot of time is spent on usleep. With my app reacting slow as it does, I wonder if this long sleeping periods could be reduced to make the app more responsive.

Thanks,
Joel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see two major things being called here, Clock.unschedule - which directly correlates with on_mouse_pos. This lead me to assume that it was being called too often on certain event triggerings, causing it to cascade down the internal scheduling pipeline. The internal clock seems somewhat sensitive to getting rapidly overloaded with jobs and having had some experience in messing that up, that was the likely culprit.

Answer (score 0):

As @cruor99 pointed out in the kivy IRC forum, I was calling Clock.unschedule too many times and indeed, when I removed these unnecessary calls, the profile didn't contain these high percentages anymore.
btw, it seems that the kivy IRC channel is the best place to go to with questions